# How to use different cookies for each connection using HttpURLConnection and the CookieManager in Java

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection, cookiestore

I needed to connect to a website from multiple threads simultaneously using HttpURLConnection, but use different cookies for each connection. Since Java only supports setting a global CookieManager, I've implemented the following hack.

Instead of calling `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager())`, I've implemented a custom `CookieHandler` which uses a different `CookieStore` instance for every thread, which is cleared after each request.

I've created class called `SessionCookieManager` based on the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/CookieManager.java) of `CookieManager`.

The `cookieJar` member variable was removed, and its usage has been replaced by `getCookieStore()`.

The following code was added:

```
public class SessionCookieManager extends CookieHandler {
    private final static SessionCookieManager ms_instance = new SessionCookieManager();

    public static SessionCookieManager getInstance() {
        return ms_instance;
    }

    private final static ThreadLocal<CookieStore> ms_cookieJars = new ThreadLocal<CookieStore>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized CookieStore initialValue() { return new sun.net.www.protocol.http.InMemoryCookieStore(); }
    };

    public void clear() {
        getCookieStore().removeAll();
    }

    public CookieStore getCookieStore() {
        return ms_cookieJars.get();
    }
```

Before the first request, the custom `CookieManager` is set as the global default `CookieHandler`:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(SessionCookieManager.getInstance());
```

After every request, the current thread's `CookieStore` is cleared:

```
try {
    ...
} finally {
    SessionCookieManager.getInstance().clear();
}
```

Comment: Is this a question? It sounds like you are listing what you've done. Are you asking if this is a good idea? I think it is not. This code is not thread-safe. Only locking will ensure that each thread sees only its intended CookieStore. I recommend using HttpClient instead if you can. You might consider posting a code review like this here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed, but why do you think this code not thread-safe?

Comment: I misread it. I don't see any threading problems. The only negative I see is that you had to reference a Sun internal class. Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: I created a complete HowTo based on this @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305486/cookiemanager-for-multiple-threads

Answer (score 1):

One work around would be to use Cookie header directly instead sending the cookie.
See cookie header here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321(v=vs.85).aspx which you can change every call.

```
Cookie: <name>=<value> [;<name>=<value>]...
```