# CookieManager for multiple threads

Tags: java, http, cookies, https, httpcookie

I am trying to make multiple connections via threads.

But every connection seems to override the other's cookies, resulting in the connections using the wrong cookies.

inside the threaded class's constructor:

```
    manager = new CookieManager();
    manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

Any way to manage the cookies per thread or per class?

New failed try:

Now every thread is using it's own index, yet they still seem to override each other cookie-wise. Any ideas?

```
public class threadedCookieStore implements CookieStore, Runnable {
    CookieStore[] store = new CookieStore[1000];
    int index;

    public threadedCookieStore(int new_index) {
        index = new_index;
        // get the default in memory cookie store
        store[index] = new CookieManager().getCookieStore();


        // todo: read in cookies from persistant storage
        // and add them store

        // add a shutdown hook to write out the in memory cookies
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(this)); 
    }

    public void run() {
        // todo: write cookies in store to persistent storage
    }

    public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        store[index].add(uri, cookie);
    }

    public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
        return store[index].get(uri);
    }

    public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
        return store[index].getCookies();
    }

    public List<URI> getURIs() {
        return store[index].getURIs();
    }

    public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        return store[index].remove(uri, cookie);
    }

     public boolean removeAll()  {
         return store[index].removeAll();
    }
}
```

Within the class:

```
threadedCookieStore cookiestore = new threadedCookieStore(index);

manager = new CookieManager(cookiestore,CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

Comment: I can't believe how bad the java.net team are at writing APIs. Why can't we just set the cookie manager per-connection? :(  You'd think they would have learned their mistake after AuthenticationHandler.

Comment: A better solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/3794038)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

I upvoted all the answers, yet none had a complete solution.

Since google'ing this problem leads to this page here, I'll post the complete solution and accept my own answer:

HowTo:

## 1 Extend `CookieHandler` to `SessionCookieManager`

this is based on [How to use different cookies for each connection using HttpURLConnection and the CookieManager in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967883/how-to-use-different-cookies-for-each-connection-using-httpurlconnection-and-the) , nivs describes it correctly, doesn't provide a full solution tho. So most/all credit goes to him, I'm just making the complete HowTo. The SessionCookieManager is based on `Java` 's source code http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SessionCookieManager extends CookieHandler
{
    private CookiePolicy policyCallback;


    public SessionCookieManager() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    private final static SessionCookieManager ms_instance = new SessionCookieManager();

    public static SessionCookieManager getInstance()
    {
        return ms_instance;
    }

    private final static ThreadLocal<CookieStore> ms_cookieJars = new ThreadLocal<CookieStore>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized CookieStore initialValue() { return new InMemoryCookieStore(); }
    };

    public void clear()
    {
        getCookieStore().removeAll();
    }
    public SessionCookieManager(CookieStore store,
                         CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
    {
        // use default cookie policy if not specify one
        policyCallback = (cookiePolicy == null) ? CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL //note that I changed it to ACCEPT_ALL
                                                : cookiePolicy;

        // if not specify CookieStore to use, use default one

    }
    public void setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy cookiePolicy) {
        if (cookiePolicy != null) policyCallback = cookiePolicy;
    }

    public CookieStore getCookieStore() {
        return ms_cookieJars.get();
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>>
        get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders)
        throws IOException
    {
        // pre-condition check
        if (uri == null || requestHeaders == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");
        }

        Map<String, List<String>> cookieMap =
                        new java.util.HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        // if there's no default CookieStore, no way for us to get any cookie
        if (getCookieStore() == null)
            return Collections.unmodifiableMap(cookieMap);

        List<HttpCookie> cookies = new java.util.ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        for (HttpCookie cookie : getCookieStore().get(uri)) {
            // apply path-matches rule (RFC 2965 sec. 3.3.4)
            if (pathMatches(uri.getPath(), cookie.getPath())) {
                cookies.add(cookie);
            }
        }

        // apply sort rule (RFC 2965 sec. 3.3.4)
        List<String> cookieHeader = sortByPath(cookies);

        cookieMap.put("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(cookieMap);
    }


    public void
        put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders)
        throws IOException
    {
        // pre-condition check
        if (uri == null || responseHeaders == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");
        }


        // if there's no default CookieStore, no need to remember any cookie
        if (getCookieStore() == null)
            return;

        for (String headerKey : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
            // RFC 2965 3.2.2, key must be 'Set-Cookie2'
            // we also accept 'Set-Cookie' here for backward compatibility
            if (headerKey == null
                || !(headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie2")
                     || headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")
                    )
                )
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (String headerValue : responseHeaders.get(headerKey)) {
                try {
                    List<HttpCookie> cookies = HttpCookie.parse(headerValue);
                    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
                        if (shouldAcceptInternal(uri, cookie)) {
                            getCookieStore().add(uri, cookie);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // invalid set-cookie header string
                    // no-op
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /* ---------------- Private operations -------------- */

    // to determine whether or not accept this cookie
    private boolean shouldAcceptInternal(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        try {
            return policyCallback.shouldAccept(uri, cookie);
        } catch (Exception ignored) { // pretect against malicious callback
            return false;
        }
    }


    /*
     * path-matches algorithm, as defined by RFC 2965
     */
    private boolean pathMatches(String path, String pathToMatchWith) {
        if (path == pathToMatchWith)
            return true;
        if (path == null || pathToMatchWith == null)
            return false;
        if (path.startsWith(pathToMatchWith))
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    /*
     * sort cookies with respect to their path: those with more specific Path attributes
     * precede those with less specific, as defined in RFC 2965 sec. 3.3.4
     */
    private List<String> sortByPath(List<HttpCookie> cookies) {
        Collections.sort(cookies, new CookiePathComparator());

        List<String> cookieHeader = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
            // Netscape cookie spec and RFC 2965 have different format of Cookie
            // header; RFC 2965 requires a leading $Version="1" string while Netscape
            // does not.
            // The workaround here is to add a $Version="1" string in advance
            if (cookies.indexOf(cookie) == 0 && cookie.getVersion() > 0) {
                cookieHeader.add("$Version=\"1\"");
            }

            cookieHeader.add(cookie.toString());
        }
        return cookieHeader;
    }


    static class CookiePathComparator implements Comparator<HttpCookie> {
        public int compare(HttpCookie c1, HttpCookie c2) {
            if (c1 == c2) return 0;
            if (c1 == null) return -1;
            if (c2 == null) return 1;

            // path rule only applies to the cookies with same name
            if (!c1.getName().equals(c2.getName())) return 0;

            // those with more specific Path attributes precede those with less specific
            if (c1.getPath().startsWith(c2.getPath()))
                return -1;
            else if (c2.getPath().startsWith(c1.getPath()))
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in my case I changed the default value of `CookiePolicy` to `ACCEPT_ALL`

## 2 In global scope, before running any threads, call:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(SessionCookieManager.getInstance());
```

## 3 When your thread is finished, call inside of it:

```
SessionCookieManager.getInstance().clear();
```

again: not my idea, just putting it together. All credit goes to `Java` and https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442259/nivs

Answer (score 7):

Thanks, I tried to use your answer, but it was based on an old version of CookieManager (probably why you had to use ACCEPT_ALL) and referenced the package-private InMemoryCookieStore so it inspired me to the final solution.  Should have been obvious to all of us before: a ThreadLocal CookieStore proxy class.

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(new ThreadLocalCookieStore(), null));
```

with

```
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadLocalCookieStore implements CookieStore {

    private final static ThreadLocal<CookieStore> ms_cookieJars = new ThreadLocal<CookieStore>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized CookieStore initialValue() {
            return (new CookieManager()).getCookieStore(); /*InMemoryCookieStore*/
            }
    };

    @Override
    public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        ms_cookieJars.get().add(uri, cookie);
    }

    @Override
    public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
        return ms_cookieJars.get().get(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
        return ms_cookieJars.get().getCookies();
    }

    @Override
    public List<URI> getURIs() {
        return ms_cookieJars.get().getURIs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
        return ms_cookieJars.get().remove(uri, cookie);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll() {
        return ms_cookieJars.get().removeAll();
    }
}
```

Seems to be working like a charm for me

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers in this thread, I created another very simple `ThreadLocalCookieStore` implementation and pushed it to [GitHub](https://github.com/kristian/cookie-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/lc/kra/servlet/filter/helper/ThreadLocalCookieStore.java) (also providing it as a Maven dependency there):

```
public class ThreadLocalCookieStore implements CookieStore {
    private final static ThreadLocal<CookieStore> stores = new ThreadLocal<CookieStore>() {
        @Override protected synchronized CookieStore initialValue() { 
            return (new CookieManager()).getCookieStore(); //InMemoryCookieStore 
        }
    };

    @Override public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) { getStore().add(uri,cookie); }
    @Override public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) { return getStore().get(uri); }
    @Override public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() { return getStore().getCookies(); }
    @Override public List<URI> getURIs() { return getStore().getURIs(); }
    @Override public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) { return getStore().remove(uri,cookie); }
    @Override public boolean removeAll() { return getStore().removeAll(); }
    @Override public int hashCode() { return getStore().hashCode(); }

    protected CookieStore getStore() { return stores.get(); }
    public void purgeStore() { stores.remove(); }
}
```

Without much code it becomes very simple to set the cookie store, with any policy value, e.g.:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new java.net.CookieManager(
    new ThreadLocalCookieStore(), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

In addition the dependency features a small sevlet `@WebFilter`, to separate cookie stores on multiple serlvet requests if required.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a CookieHandler which manages ThreadLocal CookieManager instances.

Comment: Don't know where to start here. Any examples?

Comment: @Wurstbro - Create a CookieHandler where the methods delegate to a CookieHandler instance which is maintained in a ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 1):

The `ThreadLocal` `CookieStore` by DavidBlackledge is imo the best way to go. For the sake of memory efficiency I'm providing here a simple implementation of a regular `CookieStore` so you don't have to instantiate a whole `CookieManager` for each thread (assuming you have more than just a few).

```
/**
 * @author lidor
 * A simple implementation of CookieStore
 */
public class CookieJar implements CookieStore {

private Map<URI, List<HttpCookie>> jar;
private List<HttpCookie> freeCookies;

public CookieJar() {
    jar = new HashMap<URI, List<HttpCookie>>();
    freeCookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
}

@Override
public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
    if (uri != null) {
        if (!jar.containsKey(uri))
            jar.put(uri, new ArrayList<HttpCookie>());
        List<HttpCookie> cookies = jar.get(uri);
        cookies.add(cookie);
    } else {
        freeCookies.add(cookie);
    }
}

@Override
public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
    Log.trace("CookieJar.get (" + this + ") called with URI " + uri + " (host=" + uri.getHost() + ")");
    List<HttpCookie> liveCookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
    if (jar.containsKey(uri)) {
        for (HttpCookie cookie : jar.get(uri)) {
            if (!cookie.hasExpired())
                liveCookies.add(cookie);
        }
    }
    for (HttpCookie cookie : getCookies()) {
        if (cookie.getDomain().equals(uri.getHost()))
            if (!liveCookies.contains(cookie))
                liveCookies.add(cookie);
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(liveCookies);
}

@Override
public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
    List<HttpCookie> liveCookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
    for (URI uri : jar.keySet())
        for (HttpCookie cookie : jar.get(uri)) {
            if (!cookie.hasExpired())
                liveCookies.add(cookie);
        }
    for (HttpCookie cookie : freeCookies) {
        if (!cookie.hasExpired())
            liveCookies.add(cookie);
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(liveCookies);
}

@Override
public List<URI> getURIs() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<URI>(jar.keySet()));
}

@Override
public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
    if (jar.containsKey(uri)) {
        return jar.get(uri).remove(cookie);
    } else {
        return freeCookies.remove(cookie);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean removeAll() {
    boolean ret = (jar.size() > 0) || (freeCookies.size() > 0);
    jar.clear();
    freeCookies.clear();
    return ret;
}
}
```

So if you have this CookieJar then you can change the `ms_cookieJars` declaration to this:

```
private final static ThreadLocal<CookieStore> ms_cookieJars = new ThreadLocal<CookieStore>() {
        @Override
        protected synchronized CookieStore initialValue() { 
            return new CookieJar();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different path for the cookies. Thus it will not be overwritten.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setPath%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: sounds promising. Since I am not using single Cookies, where would I set this?

Comment: Instead of default CookieManager constructor, use the one that accepts CookieStore. You can define your own CookieStore to achive this. The CookieManager javadoc provides the details. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieStore.html

Comment: by defining a new class with the required methods? Do you know of an already made one? Would I have to extend the CookieStore or what would be the right approach?

Comment: CookieStore is an interface. You need to implement and have your own CookieStore.

Comment: You can check this page for custom cookie store implementation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/custom.html

Comment: Please check out the edit of my question. I tried to use your suggestion but am unable to make it work.

Comment: I downvoted as the setPath method seems to be for the actual cookie [domain and path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path), not where the cookie is persisted in Java. So if there's two threads both getting the same URL, each cookie with same path will still overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

How about a ThreadLocal CookieManager? Same idea as some of the other answers but seems to require less code:

```
public class ThreadLocalCookies extends CookieManager {

    private static CookiePolicy s_policy = null;
    private static ThreadLocal<CookieManager> s_impl =
        new ThreadLocal<CookieManager>() {
            @Override protected CookieManager initialValue() {
                if (null == s_policy) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Call install() first");
                }
                return new CookieManager(null, s_policy);
            }
        };

    public static void install() {
        install(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    }

    public static void install(CookiePolicy policy) {
        s_policy = policy;
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new ThreadLocalCookies());
    }

    public static void clear() {
        s_impl.set(new CookieManager(null, s_policy));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>>
    get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) 
    throws IOException {
        return s_impl.get().get(uri, requestHeaders);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String,List<String>> responseHeaders)
    throws IOException {
        s_impl.get().put(uri, responseHeaders);
    }
}
```