# HttpURLConnection with a non system-wide CookieHandler

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection, cookiemanager

I have a web application that makes HTTP requests using `HttpURLConnection`. I need it to handle cookies. I know that it's easily done by adding just one line of code, something like

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER));
```

The problem is this way I'm setting the system-wide cookie handler as the documentation describes. This also affects other web applications that run in the same servlet container. For example if I want `CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER` in one application and `CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL` in another, it won't work.

Is there a way to have a `CookieHandler` that is only used by a single `HttpURLConnection` instance?

Comment: Maybe this is a solution for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305486/cookiemanager-for-multiple-threads

Comment: @chromanoid No, the solutions from it only help to separate cookies between different threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard oracle implementation the `HttpURLConnection` get the default `CookieHandler` on the constructor, so this is one possible solution. Create a synchronized singleton factory that create the `HttpURLConnections` using a specific  manager for each application. Not good idea in my opinion.

Other bad idea is provide your own `CookiePolicy` and do the trick on the `shouldAccept` method.

Or you can manually control cookies on the app that should not share the `CookieHandler`:

```
        HttpURLConnection firstCall = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
        firstCall.connect();
        List<HttpCookie> cookieList = HttpCookie.parse(firstCall.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));
        firstCall.disconnect();
        StringBuilder cookies = new StringBuilder();
        for(HttpCookie cookie:cookieList) {
            //if(cookie.SOME_VALIDATION) {
                if(cookies.length() > 0) {
                    cookies.append("; ");
                }
                cookies.append(cookie.toString());
            //}
        }
        HttpURLConnection secondCall = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
        secondCall.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.toString());
        secondCall.connect();
        //dosomething
        secondCall.disconnect();
```

Comment: I agree that the first 2 options are bad ideas. Unfortunatelly your code also won't work in my case. The reason is the server I connect to redirects multiple times and some redirects contain cookies. If these cookies are not preserved, the server ends up redirecting in an infinite loop. I can use `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` and handle redirects manually, but it will complicate the code even more. I guess there's no good way to do it with `HttpURLConnection`, but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: There is no Parameter to change `CookieHandler` behavior and I imagine that you cannot isolate the web apps in different VMs (or can you? what is your servlet container?).  Maybe use apache HTTP client or other API that do not use HTTPUrlConnection internally.

Comment: The servlet container is Tomcat. Using multiple Tomcats is undesirable. I don't want to switch from `HttpURLConnection` because I already have a lot of code specific to it.

Comment: I ended up using some custom code to handle cookies. The idea is similar to the code in this answer, but I used `CookieManager` to save and load cookies. I also added code similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046079/2324685 because I need to preserve cookies between redirects.